# Wordpress Cron Job Not working

Tags: wp-cron, cron

can you help me with this please, what am I missing?

**This one works:**

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_hook_2' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_hook_2' );
}

add_action( 'my_hook_2', 'my_task_function' );

function my_task_function() {
  wp_mail( 'mymail@gmail.com', 'Automatic email', 'Automatic scheduled email from WordPress.');
}
```

**This one does not work:**

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_hook_3' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_hook_3' );
}

add_action( 'my_hook_3', 'my_task_function' );

function my_task_function() {
    $sql_logs = "SELECT * FROM wp_wtd_search_log WHERE year(Date) = year(CURDATE()) AND day(Date) = day(CURDATE())";
    $get_logs = $wpdb->get_results( $sql_logs );        

    $message = '<html><body><table border="5" style="border-style:none;">';

    foreach ( $get_logs as $rows){    
    $message .= '<tr><td>'.$rows->IP.'</td><td>'.$rows->Keyword.'</td><td>'.$rows->Date.'</td></tr>';
    }
    $message .= '</table></body></html>';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    mail("mymail@gmail.com","mytitle Search Logs",$message,$headers);
}
```

**Edit for comments:**

If you think this caused because of my query, I created a file with my query as below, named it as `report.php`. Then manually visited this file and received an e-mail, which I believe proves that my query works fine.

**Report.php:**

```
<?php
$inc = '../../../../wp-load.php';

if (file_exists($inc) && is_readable($inc)) {
    require_once($inc);
} else {
    require_once('wp-load.php'); 
}

$sql_logs = "SELECT * FROM wp_wtd_search_log WHERE year(Date) = year(CURDATE()) AND day(Date) = day(CURDATE())";
$get_logs = $wpdb->get_results( $sql_logs );
$message = '<html><body><table border="5" style="border-style:none;">';
foreach ( $get_logs as $rows){    
$message .= '<tr><td>'.$rows->IP.'</td><td>'.$rows->Keyword.'</td><td>'.$rows->Date.'</td></tr>';       
}
$message .= '</table></body></html>';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

mail("mymail@gmail.com","mysite Search Logs",$message,$headers);

?>
```

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by _Not Work_? Both of your codes run on cron in the same way. So I don't think it's about wp-cron. It's possibly about your query.

Comment: I strongly suspect this has nothing to do with cron, and a misunderstanding of how to use global variables, `global $wpdb;` may be all you need, and you're likely getting errors in your PHP error log when this runs

Comment: @JackJohansson What I mean is, I receive a mail from the first one, and I don't receive an e-mail from the second one. They are both inside my functions.php. I have written my query into a .php file and manually visited this file and received a mail which proved to me that my query works fine.

Comment: @TomJNowell There is no error log file created afterwards, so I don't see any errors. To check if there is some mistake in my query,  I have written my query into a .php file and manually visited this file and received a mail which proved to me that my query works fine.

Comment: An you're sure your cron job actually runs? And that error logging is turned on?

Comment: @TomJNowell , error_log files is being created time to time, (I guess that means error logging is turned on), but it is not created for this case. I am sure cron job is running, because `my_hook_2` is sending me a mail per hour, and code is excatly at the same place with `my_hook_3`, which is `functions.php`

Comment: @JackJohansson I tried and result is same. I have made more tests, and removing query makes cron job work. I simplified the query, and here it is:  `$sql_logs = "SELECT * FROM wp_wtd_search_log"; $get_logs = $wpdb->get_results( $sql_logs ); ` (If I add this, it stops working. Now I need to find what is the reason of this. )

Comment: @TomJNowell I guess that is the right answer, I misunderstood what you wanted to say. I added this line to top of my function and it all started to work. Please write this as answer and I will accept it.